# Dead kernel when using PyQt5 in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have an annoying issue where an error message indicating a 'Dead Kernel' constantly pops up anytime I run code that imports from PyQt5. As you can probably tell below, I am using Jupyter Notebooks and definitely just started learning Python.

This is the error message below in command prompt;

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
[I 14:35:25.311 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel eb77c837-9e3a-46c2-9815-c8fdae756b12 restarted
[I 14:37:07.075 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Jupyter/Untitled2.ipynb
```

I used QT designer to create a very simply gui and the code is shown below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(803, 609)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 370, 181, 51))
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 90, 211, 51))
        self.label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 803, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Press Me!"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello, my name is Bob"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**What I have tried so far?**

Unfortunately the following things below did not work for me;

1.

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
        if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        else:
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() 
        main = Main()
        main.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2. 

```
from os import environ

def suppress_qt_warnings():
    environ["QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO"] = "0"
    environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    environ["QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS"] = "1"
    environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suppress_qt_warnings()
```

Embarrassingly I spent hours scouring the internet trying to find a solution to my problem, so any help would be tremendously helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me PyQt5 scripts are working in Jupyter Notebook when you replace the last line:

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

with:

```
app.exec_()
del app
```